# ExtJS How to get dashboard part dimensions

Tags: extjs, extjs6

In a ExtJS 6 dashboard I need to get part's dimension like width and height after they are rendered into the layout, also when they are resized after drag'n'drop.

Any idea how can I get the changed dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for this events for dashboard parts:

- [`afterrender`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.dashboard.Dashboard-event-afterrender)
- [`resize`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.dashboard.Dashboard-event-resize)
- [`dragover`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.dashboard.Dashboard-event-dragover) / [`drop`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.dashboard.Dashboard-event-drop)

And get height / width of the component with this methods:

- [`getHeight()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.dashboard.Dashboard-method-getHeight)
- [`getWidth()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.dashboard.Dashboard-method-getWidth)

within event handler.